# Cannot install any ubuntu packages or run updates - error processing package

Tags: package

Thank you in advance for your help.

New Ubuntu Server 20.04. I cannot run `sudo apt upgrade`or `sudo apt install nano`

This is the error when I attempt to run `sudo apt install nano`.

```
# apt install nano
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nano is already the newest version (4.8-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/47.6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of landscape-common:
 landscape-common depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package landscape-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ufw:
 ufw depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ufw (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for gnome-menus:
 gnome-menus depends on python3:any; however:
  Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gnome-menus (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 landscape-common
 ufw
 gnome-menus
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is just an example. I cannot install any packages at all.

I can see the error is related to

```
python3
landscape-common
ufw
gnome-menus
```

but I do not know how to fix this issue. I read that this error may come due to broken packages, corrupt software installer, or maybe due to some interruptions during installation

The only things I installed before this problem arose was Anaconda. However, there was no error messages or interruptions during the install.

Thank you for your help.